# Difference between водить машину and ездить на машине?

Tags: глаголы

My dictionary says that "ездить" is the indeterminate of "ехать" which is to ride. The dictionary then says that "водить" is to operate. Can someone explain the difference to me and give some examples of when to use each.

Спасибо Большое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Водить** (машину) typically means *having skills* of a driver (plus a driver's license). It doesn't necessarily mean the person owns a car.

> Я **вожу** машину. I **can drive** a car.

**Ездить** (на машине) can either specify someone's *usual type of transportation* (driving or not) or emphasize their car *ownership*:

> Он **ездит** на машине (а не на метро; возможно, и не сам водит).
>
> Он **ездит** на Порше. (У него свой Порш.) He **drives** a Porsche.

Comment: "Порше" не склоняется и всегда заканчивается на "е".

Comment: @n0rd +1. Склоняемая форма "[Поршак](https://russian_argo.academic.ru/9602/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA)" :)

Answer (score 3):

**`ехать/ездить`** - to ride (regardless of being a passenger or the driver)

**`водить`** - to drive (being the driver)

> To ride/move in a car - Ехать/ездить на машине
>
> To drive a car - Вести/водить машину / Управлять машиной

Answer (score 2):

Ездить на машине means you can be a passenger or a driver. When you use водить,  you can be only a driver. For a driver both words are synonymous.Водить also underlines the process of operating the car.

> Он водит машину хорошо.(Он ездит хорошо sounds a bit weird,  but it can be used in colloquial speech )